# PHP array parse error

Tags: php, arrays

I have returned to PHP after a while and I guess I have started to make silly mistakes.

Does anyone have any idea why the following error is occurring?

Consider the code starting from line 1 of the page "admin.php"

```
function r($a = NULL, $b = NULL, $c = NULL, $d = NULL){
    $e = 0;
    ($a != NULL) ? $e.=$a : 'FALSE';
    ($b != NULL) ? $e.=$b : 'FALSE';
    ($c != NULL) ? $e.=$c : 'FALSE';
    ($d != NULL) ? $e.=$d : 'FALSE';
    echo($e);
}

r('a',,,'e');
```

Returns: Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\f\admin.php on line 10

Comment: you can't just ommit parameters in a function call.

Comment: Try just `r('a','e');` or `r('a','','e');`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That works but I wonder why the code I mentioned should not work!

Comment: You can't omit args in the middle.  `r('a')` works `r('a',null,null,'e');` works

Comment: As Gerald explained, you're omitting parameters. It's the `,,,` that are causing the error and are not considered as parameters, so PHP is looking for a seperated value and doesn't find one, just a comma.

Comment: yes you can omit if you assign a value to it. but in this case its the params in between

Comment: You guys are right. As attempt to type minimum characters, I figured out what I was looking for, which is this- `r('a','','', 'e');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r('a',,,'e');
```

should be:

```
r('a', null, null, 'e');
```

documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php